# % !BIB TS-program

Tags: bibliographies, texshop

When I use the macro

`% !BIB TS-program = biber`

to force TeXShop (Version 3.50 (3.50)) to use the biber as BibTex engine everything works fine, if TeXShop is not configured to use an external editor.

However, if I configure TeXShop to use an external editor, i.e., I check the box next to `Configure for External Editor` in the `Source` preference tab, then the macro

`% !BIB TS-program = biber`

is not working and the default BibTeX engine is used when I typeset the bibliography.

Can anyone confirm this behavior?

And is there a workaround to force TeXShop to use the BibTeX Engine specified via the macro `% !BIB TS-program = biber` even when TeXShop is configured to be used with an external editor?

EDIT: I would like to add, that this problem does not occur with the macro

`% !TEX TS-program = latex`

In this case, independent if I use TeXShop with the build-in editor or with an external editor, when I typeset the tex file the correct engine (latex,dvips,ps2pdf) is used. Even if my default latex engine is pdflatex.

### Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: It's the expected behaviour: The % ! instructions of TeXShop are only relevant to TeXShop's own editor. The interesting new feature you ask for should best be transmitted to TeXShop's maintainer, Richard Koch. See http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/ for more information.

Comment: What happens if you set `biber` as the default program for BibTeX? (This can be set in the Engines panel of the preferences.) Probably nothing because it's the editor that controls the compilation. But it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Alan: If I change the default engine everything works fine. That is the usual way, how I choose the bibtex engine. But of course, it would be nice, if I could spare the change and just put the macro in the source file.

Comment: @daniel You should check out [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara).